# Invalid prop 'children' of type 'array' supplied to overlay. Expected a single react element

Tags: javascript, react-native, overlay, react-props

It works just fine, and the other answers I've looked at don't really have a solution which can fit mine. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <Overlay
  isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
  onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isVisible: false })}
>
  {
    this.state.userSlugs.map((l, i) => (
    <WebView key = {i}
    source={{uri: 'https://myurl.com'+l}}
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
    injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); 
    meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3,
     maximum-scale=0.3, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); 
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
  />
    ))
  }
</Overlay>
```

Comment: You are providing an array of children to the `Overlay` component (through the use of `map`). It seems that the `Overlay` component is expecting only one react element as a child.

Comment: Try wrapping your WebView array into some container.

Comment: Hey @Clarity.  Wrapping the WebView array into a container worked. Add that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to wrap your `WebView` into some container since you're passing an array of children to `Overlay`, but it expects only one child.

Answer (score -2):

adding `<>` to overlay and `</>` before closing the overlay, for example:

```
<Overlay>
<>
.your code or other components
.
.
</>
</Overlay>
```